# Vuejs get id of watched element

Tags: postgresql, laravel, vuejs2, axios

I'm making a new app in Laravel and I decided to use Vue as well.

Now I have a table showing a bunch of data that I get from a database.
One of the rows in this table is an input field that is being watched by Vuejs.

Vue will make an Axios call to update the property in my database but I need to get the id of the element that is being watched. This table is being build up by Vuejs and the id of the object is getting passed to the element.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT780.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa9IX.png)

So I need to get the ID of the element but there is also the issue of Vuejs seeing all the rows as the same element so it changes all the rows to the same thing.

I hope you guys can help me out a bit.

Comment: Some code would make it easy to help you

Comment: I added two pictures to some code from my app.

Comment: Please write your code... the images are not optimal...

Comment: OK. I see some problems with your code:
you are binding with v-model the input to the costPrice, but then you are kind of overwriting that binding with :value= "data.cost_price excl".. Where do you want to call the updateCostprice?

Comment: I want to call the updateCostPrice the moment that something has been typed into the input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@input` event on the input element and call the method `updateCostPrice($event, id)` passing the event and `:id` as arguments

```
<input :id="data.store.data_product_id" @input="updateCostPrice($event, data.store.data_product_id)">
```

**script**

```
updateCostPrice: _.debounce(
        function(ev, id){
            var inputValue = ev.target.value;

            console.log('new price: ' + inputValue + ' element id: ' + id);
        }, 500
    )

}
```